# Unable to commit chaincode even after approving from all the orgs

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I have approved chaincode from all the organisations of the channel. As the below checkcommitereadiness command outputs the json of approvals.

```
#peer lifecycle chaincode checkcommitreadiness -o localhost:9050 --channelID supplychain-channel --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/freight.example.com/orderers/orderer0.freight.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.freight.example.com-cert.pem --name supplychain --version 1.0 --sequence 1 --output json --init-required --signature-policy "AND ('ShipperMSP.peer','FreightMSP.peer','CarrierMSP.peer','CustomMSP.peer','ConsigneeMSP.peer')"
{
    "approvals": {
        "CarrierMSP": true,
        "ConsigneeMSP": true,
        "CustomMSP": true,
        "FreightMSP": true,
        "ShipperMSP": true
    }
}
```

But while committing i get the below error

```
#peer lifecycle chaincode commit -o orderer0.freight.example.com:9050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer0.freight.example.com --tls --version 1.0 --sequence 1 --init-required --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/freight.example.com/orderers/orderer0.freight.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.freight.example.com-cert.pem --channelID supplychain-channel --name supplychain

Error: proposal failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'CommitChaincodeDefinition': chaincode definition not agreed to by this org (FreightMSP)
```

It is a multi-host fabric network which is hosted used docker swarm. Although i was able to execute all commands before commit commands in chaincode lifecycle from the host itself. But I’m getting this error

```
Error: failed to retrieve endorser client for commit: endorser client failed to connect to localhost:7051: failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:7051: connect: connection refused"
```

so to communicate to all the nodes in the swarm network I’m trying to execute commit command from CLI container and i get "failed to invoke backing implementation of 'CommitChaincodeDefinition' " error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its solved just needed to add --signature-policy also for commit:

```
peer lifecycle chaincode commit -o orderer0.freight.example.com:9050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer0.freight.example.com --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/freight.example.com/orderers/orderer0.freight.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.freight.example.com-cert.pem --channelID supplychain-channel --name supplychain --peerAddresses peer0.shipper.example.com:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/shipper.example.com/peers/peer0.shipper.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses peer0.freight.example.com:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/freight.example.com/peers/peer0.freight.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses peer0.carrier.example.com:11051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/carrier.example.com/peers/peer0.carrier.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses peer0.custom.example.com:13051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/custom.example.com/peers/peer0.custom.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses peer0.consignee.example.com:15051 --tlsRootCertFiles /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/consignee.example.com/peers/peer0.consignee.example.com/tls/ca.crt --version 1 --sequence 1 --init-required --signature-policy "AND ('ShipperMSP.peer','FreightMSP.peer','CarrierMSP.peer','CustomMSP.peer','ConsigneeMSP.peer')"
```